# Why do default buttons change color when borders are removed?

Tags: html, css

As you can see from running the snippet below, the background color becomes darker when borders are removed. I guess it has something to do with `background-color: buttonface;` in the browser's default stylesheet, but am unable to understand the short description of it on w3.

Browser: Chrome 78 on Ubuntu 18.

[image: Demonstration]

```css
.noBorder {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="noBorder">No border</button>
<button>With border</button>
```

Comment: Hey, which browser and OS are u using? Because there is no difference in the background-color for me. Both having a white background-color.

Comment: @QuentinAlbert Chrome on Ubuntu. I will add a picture in the question detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you will find an explanation of this behavior in the classic CSS world because buttons are *special* elements. You may need to dig into how each browser implements the button element to understand what is happening.

I don't have any official proof but to use easy words: buttons have default style applied by the browser (related to border and background) and if you try to alter any value you will break everything.

Examples:

```html
<button style="background-color:grey">button</button>
<button style="border-color:grey">button</button>
<button style="border-width:3px">button</button>
<button style="border-radius:5px">button</button>
<button style="border-image:none">button</button>
<button style="border-image-slice:1">button</button>
<button style="background-origin:content-box">button</button>
<button style="background-clip:content-box">button</button>
<button>button</button>
```

In the above, you will notice that all the buttons are losing their default style if we change any rule related to border or background (even irrelevant ones like `border-image-slice` or `background-clip`). In Firefox, it's different as the last four buttons will keep their default style. Don't know about the other browser but it's probably different too.

**UPDATE**

In the last version of Chrome the same thing seems to happen with input elements:

```html
<input>
<input style="border-image-slice:1">
<input style="border-image:none">
<input style="border-width:3px">
<input style="background-origin:content-box">
```

Answer (score 3):

In Chrome, the `user agent stylesheet` styles `<button>`s as:

```css
button {
    -webkit-appearance: button;
    -webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb !important;
    text-rendering: auto;
    color: buttontext;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-spacing: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    text-indent: 0px;
    text-shadow: none;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
    cursor: default;
    background-color: buttonface;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0em;
    font: 400 13.3333px Arial;
    padding: 1px 6px;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: outset;
    border-color: buttonface;
    border-image: initial;
}
```

And `border: none` is a shorthand, which translates to:

```css
{
  border-top-color: initial;
  border-top-style: none;
  border-top-width: initial;
  border-right-color: initial;
  border-right-style: none;
  border-right-width: initial;
  border-bottom-color: initial;
  border-bottom-style: none;
  border-bottom-width: initial;
  border-left-color: initial;
  border-left-style: none;
  border-left-width: initial;
  border-image-source: initial;
  border-image-slice: initial;
  border-image-width: initial;
  border-image-outset: initial;
  border-image-repeat: initial;
}
```

The properties you are probably interested in are `border-width`, `border-color` and `border-style` (the *apparently* thin darker border comes from `border-style: outset;`).

It is, indeed, quite strange how a `border-style: outset; border-width: 2px` button renders, when compared to one having a width of `1px` or `3px`:

```css
.\31 { border-width: 1px }
.\33 { border-width: 3px }
```

```html
<button class="1">border-width: 1px;</button>
<button class="2">border-width: 2px;</button>
<button class="3">border-width: 3px;</button>
```

It looks to me like Chrome is making an exception from how `outset` renders on buttons with a `border-width` of `2px`, which *happens* to be the default border width set in user agent stylesheet.

For a full explanation on what's going on, read comments, see [@Mukyuu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59100923/1891677) which, IMHO, is correct, and see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/gc9fezuj/) - forked from the one in comments.

---

**Important:** To be able to answer this type of CSS questions *yourself*, open Dev Console of Chrome (<kbd>F12</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>), select "Styles" side-tab:

[image]

, click on the element you want to inspect in the DOM tree (on left) and find the shorthand property in the Styles list. In your case, `border: none;`. You'll notice a small arrow after the the property name:

[image]

Click that arrow and you'll get the full list of what the browser parses it into.

That's how I got the information provided in this answer and my answer is true now. If standards change over time, it might become obsolete but, if you do as outlined above, you'll always get the currently "correct" answer.

Comment: It's not just that, when you use `all: initial` you would at the very minimum require
`-webkit-appearance: button;
  color: buttontext;
  background-color: buttonface;
  font: 400 13.3333px Arial;
  padding: 1px 6px;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: outset;
  border-color: buttonface;
  border-image: initial;`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying, @Mukyuu. Without touching any other property, I'd expect a `border-style: outset; border-width: 2px;` to render similarly to the ones having `1px` or `3px`, the only thing changed being the number of pixels. Still, it does not happen. The least we could say is that it renders unexpectedly. As far as I'm concerned, it's definitely classifiable as a "bug". Because one can't obtain what you normally expect from an element with a `border-style` of `outset;`.

Comment: Not sure if it was intended but I agreed that it's supposed to be a bug. Meanwhile, if you're interested I was trying to break down the button style here: https://jsfiddle.net/jcL29a5r/

Comment: Well, that's the correct and complete answer, Mukyuu. With the amendment `.p2` and `.p5` are not, really required. So you're saying in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2eaJ.png), to obtain the right-hand side button, all one has to do is apply either `border-image:none` or `background-color: #ddd`. Which is correct. However, it's a very strange decision from Chrome dev team. Having unexpected rendering results is never good, IMHO. Please add these findings to your answer, you have my upvote.

Answer (score 2):

### It depends on how the browser handles buttons related

---

The following was limited to the Chrome Browser:

When you try to use `all:`[`initial`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial) to applies the [initial (or default) value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial_value) of a property to an element. You would at the very minimum need the following style to have the default button:

```
-webkit-appearance: button;
border-width: 2px;
border-style: outset;
border-color: buttonface;
background-color: buttonface;
```

Breaking down the button style:

```css
.noBorder {
  border: none;
}

.all-init {
  all: initial;
}

.leftover {
  color: buttontext;
  border-image: initial;
  font: 400 13.3333px Arial;
  padding: 1px 6px;
}

.p1 {
  /*property #1 required*/
  -webkit-appearance: button;
}

.p2 {
  /*property #2 required*/
  border-width: 2px;
}

.p3 {
  /*property #3 required*/
  border-style: outset;
}

.p4 {
  /*property #4 required*/
  border-color: buttonface;
}

.p5 {
  /* property #5 required*/
  background-color: buttonface;
}

.whole {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  color: buttontext;
  background-color: buttonface;
  font: 400 13.3333px Arial;
  padding: 1px 6px;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: outset;
  border-color: buttonface;
  border-image: initial;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="noBorder">No border</button> <br/>
<button class="all-init">test0</button>
<button class="all-init p1">test1</button>
<button class="all-init p1 p2">test2</button>
<button class="all-init p1 p2 p3">test3</button>
<button class="all-init p1 p2 p3 p4">test4</button>
<button class="all-init p1 p2 p3 leftover">test5a</button>
<button class="all-init p1 p2 p4 leftover">test5b</button>
<button class="all-init p1 p3 p4 leftover">test5c</button>
<button class="all-init p2 p3 p4 leftover">test5d</button>
<button class="all-init p1 p2 p3 p4 leftover">test6</button><br/>
<button class="all-init p1 p2 p3 p4 p5">test7</button>
<!-- test7 is the very minimum style required -->
<button class="all-init p1 p2 p3 p4 leftover">test8a</button>
<button class="all-init p1 p2 p3 p5 leftover">test8b</button>
<button class="all-init p1 p2 p4 p5 leftover">test8c</button>
<button class="all-init p1 p3 p4 p5 leftover">test8d</button>
<button class="all-init p2 p3 p4 p5 leftover">test8e</button>
<button class="all-init p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 leftover">test8f</button>
<button class="all-init whole">test9</button>
<br/><button>With border</button>
```

Additional info: button was using `ButtonFace` which is CSS2 color name corresponding to HEX value: #F0F0F0 or RGB value: 240,240,240 to display it see more in http://www.iangraham.org/books/xhtml1/appd/update-23feb2000.html.

---

Disclaimer: As [Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif) said in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59102340/3654837)

> every browser have default style applied by the browser (related to
>   border and background) and if you try to alter any value you will
>   break everything.

You could probably see test0 and test1 working in Edge and none working in Firefox since ***it was how the browser handles buttons related***. You can see [Andrei Gheorghiu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1891677/andrei-gheorghiu) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59101230/3654837) for more detail for button complete style and debugging method.

---

As such, the most common workaround that I've seen and implemented is not to use `<button>` but other elements such as `<a>` or `<input>` to support cross-browser.

Example:

```css
.styling {
  background-color: #1cbcd8;
  color: #fff;
  border-color: #1cbcd8;
}

.styling:hover {
  background-color: #255FF9;
}

.extra {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: default; /* or pointer */
  padding: 3px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<input class="styling" type="submit" value="Test">

<a href="#" class="styling extra">Test</a>
```

Comment: Why does setting border-color change background-color of the button?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following you here. Setting border-color to any another color beside `currentColor` cause the background to darken. If `ButtonFace` is only a normal color name, why does it react like that?

Comment: Okay, so `currentColor` computes to `ButtonFace` in this case. My question is still the same though. Or did you mean that the "background color" I see is actually the color of the borders covering the whole button?

Comment: @formicini https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/color/keywords. `ButtonFace` is
part of System Colors which is the face background color for 3-D elements that appear 3-D due to one layer of the surrounding border.

Comment: I did mention that I don't get that part. Does that mean it's not actually a concrete value, but computed based on the surrounding border? And if I change the `border-color`, `background-color` will automatically change to another corresponding color also?

Comment: @formicini even if you change only the border-width the background will also change, so this isn't related to border-color

Comment: @TemaniAfif that's weird, but true. Even setting only border-style changes the color.

Comment: @formicini you won't find explanation in any Doc or the specification. It's not related to classic CSS but how browser handle buttons. First it's not the same across browser second button have a default style, if you try to change anything, you simply override the whole style. If you change background color you will also break the broder

Comment: @TemaniAfif I saw the same thing happening in Chrome, Firefox and IE and thought it was a standard; guess it's not. Would you mind posting your comment as an answer so I can mark it?

Comment: @formicini please check the updated answer, I break it down to pieces. Ignore my previous answer.